# Replace Empty String & List Property to null in object

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct for mapping in my Spring Boot application.
My source object is as below:

```
Customer{
    String id;
    String name;
    List<Facility> facilityList;
}

Facility{
    String fId;
    String fName;
    Integer off;
}
```

Before actual mapping of source to target object, I want to replace all empty value of string and list of source with null (without manual mapping)?

How to achieve this with mapstruct or any Java libraries?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`expression`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions) attribute with `@Mapping` annotation like this :

```
@Mapping(target = "fName", expression = "java(src.name.isEmpty() ? null : src.name)")
Target convert(Source src);
```